# should dao (or perhaps repository) take id's or entities as arguments

Tags: java, repository, domain-driven-design, dao

In our code base we make extensive use of DAOs. In essence a layer that exposes a low level read/write api and where each DAO maps to a table in the database.

My question is should the dao's update methods take entity id's or entity references as arguments if we have different kinds of updates on an entity.

For example, say we have customers and adressess. We could have

```
customer.address = newAddress;
customerDao.updateCustomerAddress(customer);
```

or we could have

```
customerDao.updateCustomerAddress(customer.getId(), newAddress);
```

Which approach would you say is better?

The latter is more convenient since if we have the entity we always have the id, so it will always work. The converse is not always the case though, but would have to be preceded with getting the entity before performing the update.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume your question is

> Which approach of the two is better?

I would prefer the second approach. It states clearly what will be done. The update object will be freshly loaded and it is absolutely clear that *only* the address will be updated. The first approach leaves room for doubt. What happens if `customer.name` has a new value aswell? Will it also be update?

Comment: This answer is highly incorrect in regards with how repositories shall be implemented from a DDD perspective. It could make sense for pure DAOs however.

Comment: You are absolutely right. My answer only holds with my assumed question.

Answer (score 3):

In DDD we have `Aggregates` and `Repositories`. `Aggregates` ensure that the business invariants hold and `Repositories` handle the persistence.

I recommend that `Aggregates` should be pure, with no dependencies to any infrastructure code; that is, `Aggregates` should not know anything about persistence.

Also, you should use the `Ubiquitous language` in your domain code. That being said, your code should look like this (in the application layer):

`customer = customerRepository.loadById(customerId);
customer.changeAddress(address);
customerRepository.save(customer);`